# node.setAttribute('attName',null) returns type mismatch

Tags: javascript, xml, dom, setattribute

The following code returns type mismatch Error in IE9.

```
 node.setAttribute('attributeName',null);
```

but

```
 node.setAttribute('attributeName',undefined) doesn't give an error.
```

And this is also fine:

```
 node.setAttribute('attributeName','null');
```

Any idea why this could be happening and whats a good way to fix it.

One solution is to check,

```
 if (attributeVal === null){
      attributeVal = 'null';
 },  
 node.setAttribute('attributeName',attributeVal);
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: some types of the nodes dowsn't accept attributes. Check the types before you set your 'attributename'

Comment: Note that the second parameter to [`setAttribute`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-F68F082) should be a string, not a pseudo object, which is probably why you are getting the type mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to delete an attribute, don’t use `setAttribute(name, null)`, use `removeAttribute(name)`.

I’m not sure why you would want to set falsy values at all, I would assume you either want to set something, or remove the attribute. So something like:

```
attributeVal ? 
    node.setAttribute(attributeName, attributeVal) : 
    node.removeAttribute(attributeName);
```

Comment: that makes sense. the thing is that the server expects a certain attribute and it is implemented across other clients that follow this protocol.